# Dovecot + Postfix: How to automatically send a e-mail back when requested e-mail adress is not found

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, postfix, dovecot

I currently have a e-mail server set up with dovecot and postfix, getting users from a mysql database, on an ubuntu server. I would like to know how to automatically send an e-mail to the sender if he sends an e-mail to an adress that doesn't exist.

Thank you!

Comment: That's the default behaviour of postfix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it works when Postfix is trying to deliver the message to another MTA, but fails.

If Postfix already knows during the SMTP connection that the mail cannot be delivered (domain is handled locally and mailbox doesn't exists, relay is not permitted etc.) it will give an SMTP error, instead. This is how it should work and you should not try to change this.